# Leer archivo Firebird

Tags: c#, firebird

Estoy tratando de conectar a un archivo FDB para extraer la informacion de sus tablas para migrar sus datos a SQL. Para el proceso es necesario hacerlo como un Service Worker para ir actualizando la informacion. Resulta que no estaria ni pudiendo conectar. Alguna idea? Mi codigo seria esto:

```
 using System;
 using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    FbConnection connection = CrearConexion();
 }

  public static FbConnection CrearConexion()
  {
     FbConnection conexion = new FbConnection();

     try
  {
      FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
      cs.DataSource = "localhost";
      cs.Database = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\Luis\\RP601.FDB";
      cs.Port = 3050;
      cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
      cs.Password = "masterkey";

      conexion.ConnectionString = cs.ToString();
      conexion.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(e);
      throw;
   }

    return conexion;
 }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que en el catch tengas más detalle para visualizar el error, agrega esto y verifica que te aparece " Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message); "

Comment: Gracias. La conozco pero no me detuve tanto en ver el error sino en pasar porque estaba seguro que era asi.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen a todos. Ya conecte

```
       public  FbConnection CrearConexion()
       {
        FbConnection conexion = new FbConnection();

        try
        {
            FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
            cs.DataSource = "localhost";
            cs.Database = _config.GetValue<string>("PathArchivoFDB"); // 
            pasar la ruta path donde esta el archivo "FDB"
            cs.Port = 3050;
            cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
            cs.Password = "masterkey";

            conexion.ConnectionString = cs.ToString();
            //conexion.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return conexion;
    }
```

El PathArchivoFDB esta declarada en el appsetting.json